# SDF derivation by a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, asset-pricing

I have a stochastic process to model the stochastic discount factor (SDF) with M:
\begin{equation}
dM_t = aM_tdt + bM_t d Z_t
\end{equation}
where, $Z_t$ is a standard brownian motion. How do I show that $a = -r$, where $r$ is the continuously compounded risk-free rate?
I think that I should use the following equation that the SDF requires,
\begin{equation}
E(M_t e^{rt}) = 1
\end{equation}
or,
\begin{equation}
E(M_t) = e^{-rt}.
\end{equation}
I am close to the answer, but I don't know how to put it all together to prove $a = -r$.

Also, we can setup a differential equation for a risky asset $S_t$:
\begin{equation}
dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dZ_t.
\end{equation}
How do I prove that $b = - \frac{\mu - r}{\sigma}$?

Comment: If $dM_t = aM_tdt + bM_t d Z_t$, then $E[M_t]=M_0e^{at}$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion#Properties). Typically, you impose $M_0=1$ and then you can conclude $a=-r$.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question now, do you also know how to prove the expression for $b$?

Comment: @nithingong $\frac{\mu-r}{\sigma}$ is the market price of risk (Sharpe ratio). It appears as a result of [Girsanov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girsanov_theorem), see [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/26228/41821), [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/59788/42766), [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/59789/42766) and [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/15159/41821)